# Prevent redireting for a specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm redirecting if the url contains a specific word.

```
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ /homepage.html?no=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Is it possible to avoid redirecting for a specific url that has the above specific word?

E.g.
The below gets redirect

```
http://www.exsample.com/forum/contactus.html?ypin9001234
```

to

```
http://www.exsample.com/homepage.html?no=ypin9001234
```

What I need is to continue the above redirect as it is but to avoid the redirect only for the below URL.

```
http://www.exsample.com/forum/members/gold/gold.html?ypin9001234
```

Note: The word `gold` is used only by this url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rewrite condition before your rewrite rule, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*gold.*$
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ /homepage.html?no=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

This will prevent any url containing the word gold from being rewritten. If you need to be more specific, just make the condition more precise:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^forum/members/gold.*$
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ /homepage.html?no=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

etcetera...

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `RewriteCond` with **`THE_REQUEST`** to match full URL with query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/forum/members/gold/gold\.html\?ypin9001234 [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ /homepage.html?no=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect!! Worked as expected.